# Illustrator vs InDesign - missing image path, link edits, update

Tags: adobe-illustrator, resolution, image-editing

I use InDesign where your image is linked and you can click on it to edit in photoshop and see the resolution. I'm working with another graphic designers files ALL Illustrator files. Illustrator doesn't keep links path, in links tab -the edit image, update links are grayed out, unselectable. So what do I need to know about working in Illustrator vs InDesign with rasterized images?
1.) How do I check the resolution is to know if image I can enlarged?
2.) How can I find original image?
3.) Can I copy and paste images from Illustrator file to other Illustartor or Photoshop, no original needed or import? 
4.) For printer you send just the Illustrator file no image files? I usually save as pdf but in InDesign files need to be linked up.

Answer (score -1):

I don't totally understand what you're asking but.

Since the file is greyed out in the links panel, you'll probably have to go to the file's location on your computer in order to edit it. Normally, you'd be able to select the image in the links panel, click the link panel's menu options on the top right (button with several horizontal lines and a triangle), and go down to Copy Info > Copy Full Path. This will add the image's location on your computer to your clipboard and allow you to follow the file path.

If this doesn't work, you can try going to File > Package, which will gather all of the files, fonts and links in your document together in one folder set for you. Ideally, this is how InDesign documents are transferred between separate people working from separate stations, since it is used to keep files in order and prevent links from breaking. If you really can't find the image files after this, you might want to ask that other person to deliver them again and then relink them.

Copying the AI in InDesign and moving it to AI or another program might result in the destruction of some of the elements in the artwork. For example, strokes and 3D effects might wind up being expanded, which can be a big problem depending on what you need to edit.